# Can't align oversized image to center of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code for an image that is larger than the div it exists in, however I need it to be centered so the middle of the image shows in the div, right now it starts at the left of the image and gets cut off. I'm not sure what code will center it.

EDIT: SOLVED MY SOLUTION IS BELOW THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR HELP

here is the code:

```css
.about {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.about-img {
  content:url("//placehold.it/1000x1000");
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
    <img class="about-img"/>
</div>
<div><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p><p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `src` attribute for the `<img>` tag?

Comment: In the code on the website it uses different images for mobile and I need them to be set in css media queries. that shouldn't effect centering it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you is you have a static height for the image. 
You can set the height to 100vh in the about-image class to set the image height to the full page height.

```css
.about {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.about-img {
  background :url("//placehold.it/1000x1000") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  // height: 100px; //static height
  // height: 100vh; // full page height
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
    <img class="about-img"/>
</div>
<div><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p><p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div>
```

Comment: This isn't what I need, I need the hight to be the inherit hight of the image. I don't want to use a background-image i need to use an actual image.

Comment: then remove the height property from .about-image

Comment: I was able to use your answer but instead I set background-size: auto 1000

Comment: * and set the width to auto and height to 1000

Answer (score 0):

If you target your image & and make it's width = to 100% of your container, it should work. Worked when I tested it out.

Just target your image like this:

```
img {
```

width: 100%;
}

Comment: This makes the image fit to the page. I need it to retain it's original height and width, I just want it to be centered. not to change the size to fit my page

Answer (score 0):

This will center the image . Though you need to set height of image to some `px` to make it look neat.

```css
.about {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.about-img {
  content:url("//placehold.it/1000x1000");
  display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
    <img class="about-img"/>
</div>
<div><p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p><p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div>
```

Comment: This changes the image width. I need the image to stay the same height and width but to be centered

Comment: I don't think size will be a matter here. I changed to 1000X1000. I'm setting width to 100% in a block .

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with this code: assuming you know the image height:

```
.about {
    background:url(../5678site/images/aboutback.png) no-repeat center top;
    background-size:auto 1216px;
    height: 1217px;
    width:auto;
}
```

this code doesn't include an img in html or css by the way its just the div